# OpenLayers - Create multiple Maps using for-loop

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a bunch of checkboxes with the class 'layercheckbox' and want to create the divs for each map (there should be the possibility to show different combinations etc.) and create the ol.Map in the div.
They are inactive (display='none') in the beginning and on changing the checkbox will be shown via a change of class. This part is working.

If I check my website the ol-viewports are in the respective divs, but there are no requests sent to the server and no indication of a map in the divs. No Zoombuttons etc.

```
var center_start = [601200, 5669000];
var zoom_start = 4;
var projection25832 = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:25832',
        // The extent is used to determine zoom level 0. Recommended values for a
        // projection's validity extent can be found at https://epsg.io/.
    extent: [-1877994.66, 3932281.56, 1836715.13, 9440581.95],
    units: 'm'
}); 

// Mapview
var view = new ol.View({
    projection: projection25832,
    center: center_start,
    zoom: zoom_start
    });

var OSMgreysource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'https://ows.terrestris.de/osm-gray/service?',
            params: {
               'LAYERS': "OSM-WMS",
               'VERSION': '1.1.0',
                'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                'TILED': false
                }
                });


var createMap = function(divid){
    var osmgrey = new ol.layer.Tile({
            name: 'osmg',
            visible: false,
            class: 'basemap',
            source: OSMgreysource}); 

    var curmap = new ol.Map({
        target: divid,
        layers: [osmgrey],
        view: view
        });      

    maparray.push(curmap); 
}

var maparray = [];

// Iterate over the checkboxes and create divs and maps
var layercheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[class="layercheckbox"]');
for (var i=0; i<layercheckboxes.length; i++){
        var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map");
        var submap = document.createElement('div');
        submap.className = 'submap_inactive';
        submap.id = "submap_" + layercheckboxes[i].id;
        mapdiv.appendChild(submap);
        createMap(submap.id)
}


var mapcount = 0;

$('input:checkbox[class="layercheckbox"]').change(
    function(){
        if(this.checked === true){
            document.getElementById("submap_"+this.id).className = 'submap_active'
            mapcount += 1;
            rearrangeSubmaps();
        }else{
            document.getElementById("submap_"+this.id).className = 'submap_inactive'
            mapcount -= 1;
            rearrangeSubmaps();
        }
    }
);


var rearrangeSubmaps = function(){
    if(mapcount < 4){
        var pixel_from_border = mapcount * 4;
        $(".submap_active").css("width","calc(100%/" + mapcount +" - "+pixel_from_border+"px)");  
        $(".submap_active").css("height","100%");  
        $(".submap_active").css("position","relative");
    }else if(mapcount%2 === 0 && mapcount <12){
        // Gerade Anzahl an Maps
        var pixel_from_border = mapcount/2 * 4;
        $(".submap_active").css("width","calc(100%/"+mapcount/2+" - "+pixel_from_border+"px)");  
        $(".submap_active").css("height","50%");  
    }else if(mapcount%3 === 0){
        var pixel_from_border = mapcount/3 * 4;
        $(".submap_active").css("width","calc(100%/"+mapcount/3+" - "+pixel_from_border+"px)");  
        $(".submap_active").css("height","calc(100%/"+mapcount/3+" - "+pixel_from_border+"px)");            
    }else{
        if(mapcount === 5){
            var pixel_from_border = 3 * 4;
            $(".submap_active").css("width","calc(100%/"+3+" - "+pixel_from_border+"px)");  
            $(".submap_active").css("height","calc(100%/"+2+" - 8px)");    
        }else if(mapcount === 7){
            var pixel_from_border = 3 * 4;
            $(".submap_active").css("width","calc(100%/"+3+" - "+pixel_from_border+"px)");  
            $(".submap_active").css("height","calc(100%/"+3+" - "+pixel_from_border+"px)");  
        }else if(mapcount === 11){
            var pixel_from_border = 4 * 4;
            $(".submap_active").css("width","calc(100%/"+4+" - "+pixel_from_border+"px)");  
            $(".submap_active").css("height","calc(100%/"+4+" - 16px)");     
        }else if(mapcount === 13){
            var pixel_from_border = 5 * 4;
            $(".submap_active").css("width","calc(100%/"+5+" - "+pixel_from_border+"px)");  
            $(".submap_active").css("height","calc(100%/"+3+" - 12px)");     
        }
        
    }
    maparray.forEach(map => map.updateSize());
};
```

EDIT:
If I remove the whole changing of the css-values of the class "submap_active" and just use fixed value for height and width it is working as intended.

I feel like this should be possible but I am missing something minor.

Comment: If you change the visibility of a map div you should call `.updateSize()` method of the map object.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I actually got a little further by now. If i comment the whole part in the rearrangeSubmaps-function that changes the size of the divs and just let the updateSize()-line there, it is actually working. Now I only have to figure out how to dynamically change the size of the divs.

Answer (score 0):

So apperently my code works perfectly fine if one is able to set the parameters in css right. Sorry for anyone working on this. I am dumb.